# Go Templates error 'can't evaluate field' when the field is a method returning a slice

Tags: go, templates

I am using go to produce a table which shows industries as rows, and their products as columns. So (simplified) I would like to produce a table something like this:

[image]

For this purpose I created an Industry type and a Stock type as follows:

```
type Industry struct {
    Id   int32
    Name string
}

type Stock struct {
    Industry_id int32
    Name        string
    Quantity    int32
}

var stocks []Stock = []Stock{
    {1, "Cars", 4},
    {2, "Trucks", 6},
}

var industries []Industry = []Industry{
    {1, "Ford"},
    {2, "Amazon"},
}
```

These are simplified to illustrate the problem. In the (eventual) working app, they are saved and retrieved from a database and Stock.Industry_id is a foreign key to the industry table.

Thus it's a many-one relation: each industry can own several stocks but each stock only belongs to one industry.

I am trying to do this using an industry method that retrieves its stocks as a slice of Stock

```
// standin for database retrieval of all stocks belonging to this industry
func (industry Industry) MyStocks() []Stock {
    return stocks
}
```

This is then passed into a template as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Cars</th>
    <th>Trucks</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{ range . }}
    <tr>
      <td>{{.Name}}</td>
      {{range .Mystocks}}
      <td>{{.Mystocks.Quantity}}</td>
      {{end}}
    </tr>
    {{ end}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but I get this error:

```
executing "fails.html" at <.Mystocks>: can't evaluate field Mystocks in type main.Industry
```

It seems that the template engine won't allow a call to a method that yields a slice or array. I recall seeing something to this effect in the docs but may have misunderstood it.

Is there another better way to achieve the result required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `range .Mystocks`, `.` refers to an instance of `Stock`. Change it to

```
<td>{{.Quantity}}</td>
```